# Linked / Sync files in different folders in git

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two main folder in git project and I want to share files between these two folders. I want to have file_A in project A and file_B in project B and file_A/file_B always synced.

```
git_project /
git_project / A / file_A
git_project / B / file_B
```

If I made a change in file_A, file_B is updated and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You can use symbolic link file, but I don't know if that works on Windows.

Use relative path to avoid trouble:

```
cd git_project/B
ln -s ../A/file_A file_B
```